# How to create link to linux server

Tags: server, users, connection

In these days I'm setting up a small network with about twenty computers. The users of this network used windows before and they need to access samba ubuntu folders simply using their name (which is same as their login) and password (there's no problem for them with typing access data). In that case I need the simplest way for them to access it. 
I was thinking of using links (I found out it's impossible) and bookmarks are working well, but I need the solution to be cloneable (I'm cloning user accounts to another computers in the network - /etc/passwd and home directories). Is there any way how to do it simply?

**EDIT**: If the things upper are not simply possible, please tell me at least some way how to connect to a single server called "Server-desktop".

Comment: I'm sure you can just make some shortcuts and edit them per user. Also, since this question is more about Windows computers, I would suggest taking this question over to [http://serverfault.com/](http://serverfault.com/). You'll probably get a better response over there.

Comment: How can I please make that shortcuts? It's all I simply need.

Comment: @camconn It's not about Windows. He said "the users of this network used windows before".

Comment: @EricCarvalho Oops. Thanks for pointing that out.